# Is there no way to run iPad OS 16.3 Sims in xcode right now?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ipados

I'm trying to fix a bug on a device running iPad OS 16.3, but xcode doesn't seem to be able to speak 16.3, best it can do is 16.2

Is there a way to run 16.3 on xcode right now? I can't find a manual download, and it's not in the xcode platforms list, even though it's live on devices.

Comment: Have you ever tested on a real iPad or have you only used simulators?  It is unusual for a point release to introduce bugs. If you have never tested on a real device that is more likely the issue.

Comment: It's on a real device that I see the bug, or at least a few users have seen a UI issue and sent screenshots. I do have a 16.3 iPad lying around, but I'm not seeing the same thing and I'm not certain why. My thought is, xcode doesn't properly speak 16.3 since the best it has is 16.2

Comment: If you build and run on a real 16.3 iPad then it is the same code that your users are running except they are running a release build. So you see the bug if you run a release build rather than debug build?

Answer (score 2):

The iOS 16.3 simulator is not available, so we can't test anything on a device running iOS 16.3 yet. Hopefully Xcode will be updated soon!

**Edit**: After a complete reinstallation of Xcode 14.2, you can now run a simulation on a device running iOS 16.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade Xcode to latest version and then restarted both mac and the phone. It worked successfully.

Prior to this, I also upgraded the OS from Monterey to Ventura, which I dont think required for ios16.3 to work.